# Volume of each of the 4 or 6 square pyramids that fit in a cube is 1/3 of the cube?

Tags: education, volume

Websites show different arrangements of a cube with square pyramids - 3 or 6:

- 3 square pyramids fit in a cube
- 6 square pyramids fit in a cube

Volume of square pyramid = (1/3) (B) (h)

Do each of the 6 square pyramids have a volume of 1/3 of the cube (when 6 square pyramids fit in a cube)?

Do the 6 square pyramids become 3 equal pyramids, each with 1/3 cube volume?

UPDATE:
Image link:
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5pBigy5Cwo8/maxresdefault.jpg

Video link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pBigy5Cwo8

Comment: Without a link to the diagram it is difficult to comment on what is represented.  Anwyay, if 6 congruent triangles fit together to form a cube, each must be 1/6 the volume of the cube.  The obvious way to fit these together is to place the vertices of the pyramids at the center of the cube and the bases on the faces of the cube.  Each pyramid has a base of $s^2$ and a height of $\frac 12 s.$

Comment: Thanks, Doug; but formula for volume of square pyramid = 1/3 Bh, so visual is not matching the formula for volume for me.  Am I missing something logical here?

Comment: If $B  =s^2$ and $h = \frac 12 s$ then $V = \frac 16 s^3$

Comment: Very nice YouTube video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the correct formula for the volume of a square pyramid is $V=Bh/3$. However, it is up to *you* to decide what $B$ and $h$ choices are relevant to the problem at hand and how to apply the formula to get a reasonable answer.

---

The two different answers you are seeing (3 versus 6) depends on where each geometer decided to put the peaks of their pyramids.

If one puts the "peak" in the very center of a cube that has side lengths $s$, then each face of the cube creates its own identical pyramid (1-of-6) with $V=Bh/3$ but with $B=s\cdot s$ and $h=s/2$.

On the other hand, if the geometer decided that the pyramids didn't have to be identical, they might instead put the peak on an outside corner.  In which case, each of the three faces touching that corner do not create pyramids as they would have zero height, but each of the three faces opposite that corner would create pyramids (with $V=Bh/3$ but $B=s\cdot s$ and $h=s$).

Either way you get $s^3$ for the final volume of the cube.  The 3-or-6 distinction just depends on how you precisely decide to cut it up. (Heck, we could break the original cube into 8 smaller cubes and then say there are 24-or-48 pyramids to work with... or cut it into 27 smaller cubes... etc.)

Comment: The paper-craft image you added to your posting is actually quite informative, as it shows three different ways to cut up a cube: 6-identical pyramids that meet in the hidden center of the cube, 3-identical pyramids that meet at one corner, and 4-identical pyramids plus a 5th odd-man-out pyramid that all meet at the center of an outside face.

Comment: Wow, thank you, AmateurDotCounter - expalnation really helped my weak visual-spatial ability!